# How to split a numbers separably from '.'?

Tags: groovy

I have code like this:

```
def a = [".15", "7..", "402", "..3"]
c = a.permutations() as List
println c[0].join()
```

Which outputs `7....3402.15`. In this one, I need to get only numbers, i.e `7,3402,15`. Even more notably I need there sums i.e in our example we would get `7,9,6`.

How this can be done in groovy?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: ha ha.. Not exactly.. Its my doubt. I'm solving a puzzle in Top coder. And ya atleast give me a clue of how I can do that.. Will code it :)

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: I can iterate over it and put in list until I find a `.` and sum it. But I guess there will be some groovier solutions to this situation ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick response, one solution would be:

```
def result = [".15", "7..", "402", "..3"].permutations()*. 
  join()*.                                 // Join each permutation together into a single string
  split( '\\.' )*.                         // Split each of these Strings on the '.' char
  findAll()*.                              // Remove empty elements (where we had '..' before splitting)
  collect { it -> it*.toInteger().sum() }  // Convert each String to List<Integer> and sum
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ? 
It's not very nice looking code, but it should convey the intent...

```
[".15", "7..", "402", "..3"].permutations()*.join()*.replaceAll('\\.\\.*',',')*.split(',')*.collect{it.getChars().inject(0){a,b->a+ (new Integer(b as String))}}
```

Edit: changed code so that it works for the whole array of permutations, not just for one element. The type conversion is clunky, @tim_yates code is much cleaner.

The code works as follows:

for each sub array of the permutation :

- Join array to one string
- Substitute all successive `.` with one `,`
- Split the string apart at the `,`

  - convert all chars in this string to integers and add them up using the `inject` method

Now, i don't know if that is what you need since I don't know the original problem.

Comment: +1 your idea is good. But can u explain a bit, what your doing?